# How to match regular expression group capture collection with another group capture collection?

Tags: c#, regex

I've defined a regular expression that parses individual HTML tags. I'm not parsing whole DOM tree though, just individual tags so therefore regular expressions seemed a good match.

Suppose I have a tag like:

```
<input type="text" disabled value="Something" />
```

I've defined my regular expression to parse tags as:

```
<(?<closing>/)?(?<tname>[a-z][a-z0-9]*)(?:\s+(?<aname>[a-z0-9-_:]+)(?:=(?<quote>['""])(?<avalue>[^'""<>]*)\k<quote>)?)*(?<selfclosing>\s*\/)?>
```

So to make it more readable let's break it down

```
1  <
2      (?<closing>/)?
3      (?<tname>[a-z][a-z0-9]*)
4      (?:\s+
5          (?<aname>[a-z0-9-_:]+)
6          (?:=
7              (?<quote>['""])
8              (?<avalue>[^'""<>]*)
9              \k<quote>
10         )?
11     )*
12     (?<selfclosing>\s*\/)?
13 >
```

Lines:

- 1 & 13 - tag start and end
- 2 & 12 - whether it's a closing or self-closing tag
- 3 - captures tag name
- 4-11 - capture any attributes that are defined on tag (hence the `*` at the end)
- 5 - attribute name
- 6-10 - non capturing group attribute value if it's present (hence the `?` at the end)
- 6 - matches `=` sign
- 7 - defines qhich quote is being used (single or double quote)
- 8 - captures attribute value
- 9 - matches the same closing quote that was used for opening attribute value

### Problem

When I try parsing my aforementioned `input` tag which has three attributes I can access all attribute names easily by:

```
match.Groups["aname"].Captures
```

but I would also want to match their values. So here lies a problem as attribute 2 has no value.

**How do I match these `match.Groups["aname"].Captures` with `match.Groups["avalue"].Captures`**? My regular expression

Comment: don't use regex for parsing html!

Comment: **I'm not parsing HTML**. I'm parsing tags... That's different because tags are nothing more than simple non-hierarchical strings.

Comment: your expression contains an error atm

Comment: @greenfeet: does it? Where?

Comment: According to [regexr](http://regexr.com/3b9g9) you have many unexcaped characters, like `/` and `?`. Don't know if c# complains about that.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik https://regex101.com/r/cE2oE8/1

Comment: @gunr2171, greenfeet: These are false positives as I'm writing regular expression for C#.

Comment: @greenfeet: https://regex101.com/r/cE2oE8/2 Updated it by escaping slash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
<
(?<closing>/)?
(?<tname>[a-z][a-z0-9]*)
(?:
  \s+
  (?<aname>[a-z0-9-_:]+)
  (?:
    =?
    (?<quote>['"]?)
    (?<avalue>[^'"<>]*)
    \k<quote>
  )
)*
(?<selfclosing>\s*\/)?
>
```

It will match some invalid markup:

```
<input type="text" disabled"" value="Something" />
<input type="text" disabled= value="Something" />
```

but you can fix this by adding lookaheads:

```
<
(?<closing>/)?
(?<tname>[a-z][a-z0-9]*)
(?:
  \s+
  (?<aname>[a-z0-9-_:]+)
  (?:
    (?:
      =
      (?=\S)|
      (?=\s)
    )
    (?<quote>['"]?)
    (?<avalue>[^'"<>]*)
    \k<quote>
  )
)*
(?<selfclosing>\s*\/)?
>
```

`aname` and `avalue` would be aligned.

Comment: Your second regular expression does the almost alright. I just had to adjust it so that it also parses non quoted attribute values is in `value=1`. But other than that, the problem I was having was that number of captures between each match groups was different and your regular expression solved that.

Answer (score 0):

### Final solution

Just for future reference I'm adding code that I implemented at last. Regular expression is a bit more complex than in the question but it correctly parses tags (opening and closing ones) in HTML string. It uses some positive lookbehinds as capturing groups can't be used in conditionals because they're part of quantified blocks. What I mean by this is that I could write

```
<?<hasvalue>=)?
```

which would correctly detect whether attribute has a value assigned to it. But the problem is that this named capture group is part of `attribute` named capture group which has a quantifier `*` (zero or more attributes). The problem with `hasvalue` arises when we start parsing a state attribute that was preceeded by a valued one. The way that regular expression processor works it will still read previous attribute's `hasvalue` success state. That's why I'm rather using lookbehinds in conditionals as they're non capturing and processor doesn't keep their state in any way shape or form.

Instead of lookbehinds one could use [balancing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html), but that would make following regular expression .net only and not universal(ish). That's why I opted for lookbehinds so it can be used in other environemnts with different regular expression processors. Those processors that don't support named capture groups may still use this regular expression, one would only need to remove group names and refer to group indices.

> **Important note**: Mind that attribute name captures count doesn't match attribute value captures count which was my initial issue with regular expression parsing. So instead of matching those counts *I'm matching attribute names with equal signs*. This way I always know whether some attribute is a state-only attribute (i.e. `selected` or `disabled`) or a valued one (i.e. `value="42"`). You'll see in below code how attribute names and values get matched using this info.

#### Regular expression

```
<                           # TAG START
(?<isclosing>\/\s*)?            # is this a closing tag
(?<tag>[\w:-]+)                 # capture tag name
(?<attribute>
    \s+                         # every attribute starts with at least one space
    (?<name>[\w:-]+)            # capture attribute name
    \s*                         # there may be arbitrary spaces between attribute name and '='
    (?<hasvalue>=?)             # is this a state or valued attribute
    (?(?<==)                    # if it's a valued attribute process its value
        \s*                     # there may be arbitrary spaces between '=' and attribute value
        (?<quote>['"]?)         # if value is quoted, capture its quote type
        (?<value>               # capture raw value without quotes if present
            (?(?<=')
                [^']*|          # parse single quoted attribute value
                (?(?<=")
                    [^"]*|      # parse double quoted attribute value
                    [\w]+       # parse unquoted attribute value
                )
            )
        )
        \k<quote>               # quotes must match each other
    )
)*
\s*                             # there may be some spaces before tag end
(?<selfclosing>\/)?             # is this a self-closing tag i.e. '<br/>'
>                           # TAG END
```

#### Parsing code

This is an excerpt of actual code that parses tags from HTML text

```
IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> tagAttributes;
StringBuilder parsedText = new StringBuilder();

char character;
for (int index = 0, length = htmlContent.Length; index < length; index++)
{
    character = htmlContent[index];

    if (character == '<')
    {
        Match tagMatch = tagRegex.Match(htmlContent, index);

        // prevent parsing of invalid HTML with incomplete tags like <tabl<p>This is a paragraph</p>
        if (tagMatch.Index != index)
        {
            parsedText.Append("&lt;");
            continue;
        }

        if (tagMatch.Groups["attribute"].Success)
        {
            tagAttributes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            // attribute count and their type counts (valued or state only) match
            var attributes = tagMatch
                .Groups["name"]
                .Captures
                .Cast<Capture>()
                .Select(c => c.Value)
                .Zip(
                    tagMatch
                        .Groups["hasvalue"]
                        .Captures
                        .Cast<Capture>()
                        .Select(c => c.Value == "="),
                    (name, isvalued) => new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(name, isvalued)
                );

            // attribute values count may be less than there are attributes
            IEnumerator<string> values = tagMatch
                .Groups["value"]
                .Captures
                .Cast<Capture>()
                .Select(c => c.Value)
                .GetEnumerator();

            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                tagAttributes.Add(
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                        attribute.Key,
                        attribute.Value && values.MoveNext() ?
                            values.Current :
                            null)
                );
            }
        }

        /* Do whatever you need with these
         *
         * TAG NAME <= tagMatch.Groups["tag"].Value;
         * IS CLOSING <= tagMatch.Groups["isclosing"].Success;
         * IS SELF CLOSING <= tagMatch.Groups["selfclosing"].Success;
         * ATTRIBUTES LIST <= tagAttributes
         */

        // advance content character index past currently regex matched tag definition
        index += tagMatch.Length - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        parsedText.Append(character);
    }
}
```

This will correctly parse tags with attributes that may be state-only or valued. Valued attributes may have unquoted, single or double quoted values. Quoted values may be empty strings.